# query table row with matching numbers?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Okay I'm relatively new to php, and at the moment, I'm completely lost!

I have a page for users to compare up to three products, and at the same time, save their search to a table `("saved_results")` so that that I can have a section, for lets say, recent searches, or similar searches, etc....

What happens is, as the user compare multiple products, it takes the product ids they're comparing from the products table `("products")` and saves it to a new table `("compared_products")` in the db, in the field `compared_ids`, using a comma separated format (id1, id2, id3).

**how can I make a query to return fields in the "saved_results" where at least two of the comma separated fields are the same?**

I'm assuming I can't use a LIKE statement, I dont *think* it would work because if I wanted to find a row where someone compared product 1 and 5, it would return any row with one of those numbers, including  lets say 10, 11, 15, 16...25, 50,51,52.... because 1 and/or 5 are in all those numbers!

Comment: You could probably use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: provided a suggestion. Check if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a little change in your table structure. To store comma separated values in table rows in a wrong fashion.

Generate a unique `compare_id` for each user at a particular time.
And restore your `compared_products` table with following structure -

```
id
compare_id
product_id
...
...
```

Hence, if one particular compare there are 3 products compared, you'll insert 3 rows instead on 1.

```
id   compare_id   product_id
1       33           52
2       33           37
3       33           11
```

Which'll in turn help you in querying easily.

Comment: but then I dont want to insert the same thing twice, as it would quickly get redundantly large! so how would I be able to make sure 52, 37 and 11 are not already in there and grouped together already before I create the new row? this would not be a bad idea at all if I can check to make sure that exact same search was not done before, because  there will also be a row for views, so I can show the most viewed comparisons.